# PHP Regex not working as expected

Tags: php, regex

I have the path of a file and I want to extract parts of it with a regex.
But the pattern seems to be wrong, it only gives me the last match.

```
$s = 'engine/plugins/renderer_smarty/plugins/css_minify/';
preg_match('@^engine/(plugins/(.+?)/)+$@i',$s,$matches);
```

Result:

```
array (3):
    0 => string (50): "engine/plugins/renderer_smarty/plugins/css_minify/"
    1 => string (19): "plugins/css_minify/"
    2 => string (10): "css_minify"
```

Expected result:

```
array (5):
    0 => string (50): "engine/plugins/renderer_smarty/plugins/css_minify/"
    1 => string (24): "plugins/renderer_smarty/"
    2 => string (15): "renderer_smarty"
    3 => string (19): "plugins/css_minify/"
    4 => string (10): "css_minify"
```

What's wrong in the pattern?

Thanks!

Comment: What about just `preg_match_all('@(?<=/)plugins/([^/]+)@i',$s,$matches);`? **See [this demo](https://ideone.com/v2LLD3)**. The issue you are facing is a by design regex repeated capturing group behavior, only the values captured with the last iteration are stored in the group memory buffer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's the solution! I didn't know that only the last iteration is stored.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
preg_match_all('@(?<=/)plugins/([^/]+)@i',$s,$matches);
```

to *match* all the substrings you need.

See [this PHP demo](https://ideone.com/v2LLD3) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Uf6yVk/1). The issue you are facing is a by design regex repeated capturing group behavior, only the values captured with the last iteration are stored in the group memory buffer.

**Pattern details**:

- `(?<=/)` - a [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) check if there is a `/` on the left, if yes,proceed matching...
- `plugins/` - a literal `plugins/` substring
- `([^/]+)` - Group 1: one or more (due to [`+` quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)) chars other than `/` (the `[^/]` is a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) matching any char but the one(s) defined in the class.